# Howto flatten a nested List?

Tags: swi-prolog

I use maplist(getEdgeInfo(Q_From_To), Edges, Edge_Info0) to collect all the information for the edges in a graph. getEdgeInfo(Q_From_To) returns a list of edges and the information for each list is also returned as a list so I end up with the following Edge_Info0:

```
[ [[4,4,"n.v.t.",3,"n.v.t.",3,5,5,2]],
  [[5,5,"n.v.t.",3,"n.v.t.",3,12,12,2],[5,5,"n.v.t.",3,"n.v.t.",3,12,12,1]],
  [[5,5,"n.v.t.",3,"1.0",3,56,56,2]],
  ---
]
```

What I need is the same data in the following format:

```
[ [4,4,"n.v.t.",3,"n.v.t.",3,5,5,2],
  [5,5,"n.v.t.",3,"n.v.t.",3,12,12,2],
  [5,5,"n.v.t.",3,"n.v.t.",3,12,12,1],
  [5,5,"n.v.t.",3,"1.0",3,56,56,2],
  ---
]
```

What is the best approach to do this?Should I use DCG? (I don't have any experience with DCG).

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this. Hope this will work with 'real' data.

```
clean([]) --> [].
clean([Q_Set|Tail]) --> q_set(Q_Set), clean(Tail), [].

q_set([]) --> [].
q_set([Rec_Set|Tail]) --> rec_set(Rec_Set), q_set(Tail).

rec_set([]) --> [].
rec_set([Record|Tail]) --> [Record], rec_set(Tail). 

?- X = [[[a]], [[b],[c]], [[d]]], phrase(clean(X), List).
List = [a, b, c, d],
X = [[[a]], [[b], [c]], [[d]]]
```

*/

Answer (score 0):

The first try flattened one step too deep. The following code gives the expected transformation:

```
clean([]) --> [].
clean([Rec_Set|Tail]) --> rec_set(Rec_Set), clean(Tail), [].

rec_set([]) --> [].
rec_set([Record|Tail]) --> [Record], rec_set(Tail).
```